# Установка Qt Designer

Tags: qt-designer

Хотел скачать Qt Designer с официального сайта, вылазит вот такое. Что посоветуете?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже обсуждали. Где то есть дубликат. Что делать? Думать.

Comment: Через VPN попробовать зайти.

Comment: сам вопрос похожий удалили.. но ссылку правильную нашел -  https://forum.qt.io/topic/134724/unlock-qt-in-russia/11